# Registry - get last time a value (not key) changed, and key creation date

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I want to get the last time a Name/Value in a Registry key was written. Is it possible?

I also want to get the date the key was **created** (not modified).

I know about the `RegQueryInfoKey()` function, but it looks like it works only at the key level, and gives only the modification date, not the creation date.

I looked at the API and couldn't find any thing else that can do what I want.

Comment: how i know registry store only `LastWriteTime` and only for keys, not for separate values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no in both cases. We cannot query the time a value was last modified, and we cannot query the time a key was created. The data does not exist. A Key object (i.e. `CM_KEY_BODY`) references a key control block (i.e. `CM_KEY_CONTROL_BLOCK` or KCB). The KCB has a pointer to the hive (i.e. `HHIVE`) and the index of the cell in the hive that contains the key node (i.e. `CM_KEY_NODE`), which has a `LastWriteTime` timestamp, but none of the other timestamps associated with File objects (i.e. `CreationTime`, `LastAccessTime`, and `ChangeTime`). (The KCB caches this timestamp as `KcbLastWriteTime`, but it's kept in sync with the key node.) A value is also stored in a hive cell, in this case containing a value node (i.e. `CM_KEY_VALUE`), which has the name, type, data, and flags, but no timestamp.